# What is the dark blue part of Safari web inspector network request timeline

Tags: safari-web-inspector

Title says it all, but in the picture below, what is the dark blue part of the timeline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The apple documentation is pretty poor, but the webkit documentation is somewhat better: https://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/#timeline_panel

> Solid parts of the bars show synchronous time spent on the operation, while the semi-transparent part shows the time consumed by everything this event caused (not necessarily synchronously).

Are you processing a lot of json or otherwise performing a lot of work when the request finishes?